# why isn't my code working where I m wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, list, attributes

Write a function rotate(m) that takes a list representation m of a square matrix as input, and returns the matrix obtained by rotating the original matrix clockwize by 90 degrees. For instance, if we rotate the matrix above, we get

rotate([[1,2],[3,4]])
[[3, 1], [4, 2]]
Your function should not modify the argument m provided to the function rotate().

```
def rotate(m):
k=[]
k_U=[]
for x in range(0,len(m[len(m)-1])):
    for i in range(len(m),0):
      
      k_U= k_U +[m[i-1][x]]

    k=k+k_U
    k_U.clear()

return(k)
```

print(rotate([[2,3],[5,4]]))

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested to see if your rotation logic is correct, but the likely thing you've missed is that `range(len(m), 0)` returns an empty list. You need to do `range(len(m), 0, -1)` if you want it to decrement values down to 1.

As a side note, you don't need to do `m[len(m)-1]` to get the last element, python allows `m[-1]`. I would also suggest `k_U.append(m[i-1][x])` rather than doing `k_U = k_U + [m[i-1][x]]`.